# How to parse this JSON to my POJO in Java

Tags: java, json, spring

I have this JSON structure that I'm trying to parse to a Java Object but don't know what I'm missing here.

```
{
   "response":{
      "status":1,
      "httpStatus":200,
      "data":{
         "94":{
            "Offer":{
               "id":"94",
               "name":"Survey Junkie Panel - US, CA, AU (SOI)",
               "description":"<b>Description:</b> Start earning cash and rewards by doing surveys.<br><br>\r\n<b>Requirement:</b> Email Submit<br><br>\r\n<b>Country(ies):</b> US, CA, AU<br><br>\r\n<b>Media:</b> Display, Email<br><br>\r\n<b>Restrictions:</b> No incentives; no search; no pops; no brokering; no users under 18; no SnapChat<br><br>\r\n<b>Other:</b> New pubs need to pause at 300 leads and ask to be evaluated (if higher test cap is necessary, contact your affiliate manager to discuss). If traffic quality is good, Advertiser will lift lead cap as long as quality remains consistent. New partners should not start on weekends. Contact publishers@pantherainteractive.com when you reach your assigned lead cap.<br><br>",
               "require_approval":"0",
               "require_terms_and_conditions":0,
               "terms_and_conditions":null,
               "preview_url":"https://www.surveyjunkie.com/",
               "currency":null,
               "default_payout":"1.20000",
               "protocol":"server",
               "status":"active",
               "expiration_date":"2030-12-23 04:59:59",
               "payout_type":"cpa_flat",
               "percent_payout":"0.00",
               "featured":null,
               "conversion_cap":"0",
               "monthly_conversion_cap":"0",
               "payout_cap":"0.00",
               "monthly_payout_cap":"0.00",
               "allow_multiple_conversions":"0",
               "allow_website_links":"0",
               "allow_direct_links":"0",
               "show_custom_variables":"0",
               "session_hours":"24",
               "show_mail_list":"0",
               "dne_list_id":"0",
               "email_instructions":"0",
               "email_instructions_from":"",
               "email_instructions_subject":"",
               "enforce_secure_tracking_link":"1",
               "has_goals_enabled":"0",
               "default_goal_name":"",
               "modified":1622672025,
               "use_target_rules":"0",
               "use_payout_groups":"0",
               "link_platform":"",
               "is_expired":"0",
               "dne_download_url":null,
               "dne_unsubscribe_url":null,
               "dne_third_party_list":false,
               "approval_status":"approved"
            },
            "Country":{
               "US":{
                  "id":"840",
                  "code":"US",
                  "name":"United States",
                  "regions":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               "AU":{
                  "id":"36",
                  "code":"AU",
                  "name":"Australia",
                  "regions":[
                     
                  ]
               },
               "CA":{
                  "id":"124",
                  "code":"CA",
                  "name":"Canada",
                  "regions":[
                     
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I have offer data:

```
@Getter @Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class OfferData {

  @JsonProperty("Offer")
  Offer offer;

  @JsonProperty("Country")
  Country country;

}
```

I'm already recovering de Offers correctly the problem is at the Country object.

The Country:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Country {
  Map<String, CountryData> countryData;
}
```

The CountryData:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class CountryData {
  @JsonProperty("id")
  private String id;
  @JsonProperty("code")
  private String code;
  @JsonProperty("name")
  private String name;
  @JsonProperty("regions")
  List<Region> regions;
}
```

I'm getting this error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.OfferMapper] and content type [application/json]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.Country` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.Country` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 92576] (through reference chain: com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.OfferMapper["response"]->com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.OfferResponse["data"]->java.util.LinkedHashMap["266"]->com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.OfferData["Country"])] with root cause

Comment: Could you check the json which you posted? It does not look like a valid one.

Comment: `com.sample.surveydemo.model.dto.OfferMapper` -> can you show this class?

Comment: And maybe check the json data for `"data":{ "226":{`

Answer (score -2):

Go to https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. Copy and paste the JSON data and adjust the parameters (generate getters and setters, toString e.t.c). Click on preview to see the converted JSON data in POJO format or you can download the zip file containing the POJO class.

Comment: Hi, this is not a good solver because it is generating lots of objects that I don't need and even does not count when it is a list or not. 

It is a good choice for a small object without nested objects and lists.

But thanks anyway.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).